# Store a resulting variable after some calculation in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, random

I am trying to create a reverse number game for the computer to guess my number. The program is meant to run in this way:

- I am presented with a number
- If I input '>', '<' in response to the given number, the computer should add the number to either 1 or 100 and divide by 2, depending if its lower or higher.
- After which the computer would ask if the resulting number is my number
- And so forth till I input '='.

My issue is after the calculation of adding the random number to 1 or 100 and dividing by 2, and then asking if that is my number I am trying to store that new number so that it is not repeated but it keeps repeating. This is the code:

```
import random

guesses_taken  = 0

my_name = raw_input("Hello! What is your name? ")

print ("Well {} think of a number between 1 and 100!").format(my_name)

low_list_store = list()
high_list_store = list()

rand_number = random.randint(1,100)

print("Is your number greater (>), equal (=), or less (<) than "
      + str(rand_number) + "?")

while guesses_taken < 8:

    user_response = raw_input("Please answer <, =, >: ")

    guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1

    if user_response == '<':
       low_list = (rand_number + 1) // 2
       print("Is your number greater (>), equal (=), or less (<) than  {}?").format(low_list)
       low_list_store.insert(0,low_list)
    elif user_response == '>':
       high_list = (rand_number + 100) // 2
       print("Is your number greater (>), equal (=), or less (<) than {}?").format(high_list)
       high_list_store.insert(0,high_list)
   if user_response == '=':
       print("I have guessed it!!")
       guesses_taken = str(guesses_taken)
       print("I needed {} step!!").format(guesses_taken)
       break

   if guesses_taken == 8:
       print("Sorry i'm not good at this game..")
   if user_response <> '>' and user_response <> '<' and user_response <> '=':
       print("Please input a valid response!!")
       continue
```

Answer (score 0):

The rand_number does not change anywhere in your code.
In the while loop, the script does 8 iteration over the same random number.

So that regardless of the user guess you'll always have:

`rand_number = random.randint(1, 100)`
Inside loop for all 8 iterations
`low_list = (9 + 1) // 2`

Comment: Yes I noticed that with my pycharm debugger but i still don't understand how i can fix the error. Because for the user's input to be '>' or '<' the value is to be stored in the high or low_list before each iteration.

Comment: I just figured it out but I'm still not sure how I ended up up solving it. 
I changed the low_list to rand_number and added a break and did the same for high_list and its apparently working..